# my query doesn't work as expected

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT Product.ProductName
      ,SUM(Purchase.Value)              AS TotalPurchase
      ,SUM(Sales.Value)                 AS TotalSales
      ,((TotalPurchase) - (TotalSales)) AS ProductAvailability
FROM Product 
INNER JOIN Purchase ON Product.ProductID = Purchase.ProductID 
INNER JOIN Sales    ON Product.ProductID = Sales.ProductID
GROUP BY Product.ProductName
```

I have 3 Table Product - Sales - Purchase
and i want Show product name total sales each product ,total purchase of each
product And  how many of those product still unsold

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: I think if you also want to show the unsold products , there will be no data for them products in the sales table, hence you need a `LEFT JOIN` here not an `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Product.ProductName
      ,SUM(Purchase.Value)                                 AS TotalPurchase
      ,ISNULL(SUM(Sales.Value),0)                          AS TotalSales
      ,(SUM(Purchase.Value)  - ISNULL(SUM(Sales.Value),0)) AS ProductAvailability
FROM Product 
LEFT JOIN Purchase ON Product.ProductID = Purchase.ProductID 
LEFT JOIN Sales    ON Product.ProductID = Sales.ProductID
GROUP BY Product.ProductName
```

Since you also want to show the unsold products , there will be no data for them products in the sales table, hence you need a LEFT JOIN here not an INNER JOIN.

Also the columns `TotalPurchase` and `TotalSales` are available to be called in the query they are being calculated , hence use a sub-query to manipulate these columns or use the expression itself.

Comment: well i just do as you but result are unexpected i know how many product i bought  and sold  but query return's wrong result

Comment: well i just do as you told but result are unexpected i know how many product i bought  and sold  but query return's wrong result for example i had 11 iphone5s in total purchase table and 3 of the same product in sales table but in this query that i run it shows 33 iphone5s in purchase total and 9 in sales

Comment: now i am sure some thing with join must be wrong because when i add the 3rd table  i see this wrong result help me pleas

Answer (score 0):

After 5 Hours OF playing With Query I FOUND THE ANSWER

```
SELECT  PN.ProductName,TotalPurchase ,TotalSales,TotalPurchase-TotalSales AS  ProductAvailability
FROM
((SELECT SUM(Purchase.Value) AS TotalPurchase,Purchase.ProductID FROM Purchase GROUP BY Purchase.ProductID ) AS TP
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT SUM(Sales.Value) AS TotalSales,Sales.ProductID FROM Sales GROUP BY Sales.ProductID ) AS TS
 ON tp.ProductID=TS.ProductID
 INNER JOIN
(SELECT Product.ProductName,Product.ProductID FROM Product GROUP BY Product.ProductName,ProductID) AS PN ON  PN.ProductID=TS.ProductID
)
```